# Output from C Program missing with Powershell

Tags: c, powershell

I realize that many similar questions have been answered before, but I can only find solutions for Unix systems and I'm using Powershell in Windows with MinGW.

I know my path is set properly because my Hello World program will give output, but this program does not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  float fahr, celsius;
  int lower, step, upper;

  upper = 300;
  step = 20;
  fahr = lower;

  while (fahr <= upper) {
    celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
    printf ("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
    fahr += step;
  }

}
```

No output is shown when I run the executable produced by MinGW; it just proceeds to the next line in Powershell. I've seen answers that claim you need to use ctrl-D to simulate EOF, but this is just for Unix systems. I have seen people say that ctrl-Z works for Windows, but that does not work in this case.

Comment: `lower` is not initialized. So `fahr` may be greater then `upper` and the loop is skipped.

Comment: That won't change anything and it doesn't need to be because it's in the main scope. It's set to 0 by default, and that's what it is meant to be.

Comment: Try with `int lower = 0, step = 20, upper = 300;` instead.

Comment: It's not set to 0 by default. Variables that are not inside a function are 0 by default. Inside main is inside a function.

Comment: I tried initializing lower to 0. Nothing changes.

EDIT: You are both correct. That was the problem. I just forgot to recompile.

Comment: It works just fine, [with minor changes](https://ideone.com/w4kNF6).